# IndexOf with multiple values ? C#

Tags: c#, uwp

So i have this list named Attributes filled with RoomId's ranging between 1-25 
is there anyway to use IndexOf to call more than one value?

```
attributes.IndexOf(new Attributes { RoomID = 1 });
```

so something like this would be great

```
 attributes.IndexOf(new Attributes { RoomID = 1-25});
```

Comment: `IndexOf` is used to give you the Position or index of something inside a list or maybe a string. So if you want to get an object out of a list but you dont know what index it got, you search for it. What exactly do you want to achieve here? Maybe that could help us more

Comment: how About a foreach loop?

Comment: what list-type is `attributes`? Is it `List<Attributes>`?

Comment: You need more information, what is the actual type of attributes, and what do you want to do with the indexes, i mean you could just use `linq` and `where` to filter

Comment: You can use lambdas or Linq

[LINQ][1]

[Lambda][2]


  [1]: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/linq/standard-query-operators-overview
  [2]: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/statements-expressions-operators/lambda-expressions

Comment: This question is becoming a grave yard of discarded posts, please be more specific as there is people trying to help you

Comment: @Stig it's `[Text](link)` in comments

Comment: @MatthiasBurger  It's a observablecollection

Comment: Do you want the indexes of all items that match, or the index of the first occurence?

Comment: @Cataklysim And how do i search for it ?
 I'm trying to write a method that can get all the values between 1-25 to then be able to make a switch case that does something for the values 11-25 etc

Comment: @Hubii Any suggestions how i would proceed with that ?

Comment: @Rafalon Something like that would be super useful!

Comment: @luddej *- Do you want to eat Chinese or Italian? - Yeah! Totally!* please answer my question...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can simply use linq - using the overload of [`Select`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534869(v=vs.110).aspx) that accepts a `Func<TSource, Int32, TResult>`:

```
 var indexes = attributes
     .Select((a, i) => return new {Element = a, Index = i})
     .Where(ei => ei.Element.RoomId >= 1 && ei.Element.RoomId <= 25)
     .Select(ei => ei.Index);
```

This will return an `IEnumerable<int>` containing all the indexes of the attributes that have a `RoomId` value between 1 and 25 inclusive.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to use a `FindAll` Predicate such as this;

Assuming your list contains objects known as `Room`, and each has a `RoomId`

```
List<Room> foundRooms = attributes.FindAll(delegate (Room obj) { return obj.RoomId >= 1 && obj.RoomId <= 25; });
```

Comment: This would give you the items themselves, not their indexes

Comment: @Rafalon that's true. The OP said "value" in his question, so I assumed this meant he wanted the item.

Comment: Well then `IndexOf` already was a really poor choice to begin with

Comment: This would work if it wasn't a ObservbleCollection

Answer (score 0):

Use `FindIndex(predicate)` instead of `IndexOf(item)`

```
 var a = new List<int>{1,2,3,4};
 Console.WriteLine(a.FindIndex(item => item == 3));  // 2
 Console.WriteLine(a.FindIndex(item => item == -1)); // -1
```

Comment: Great, just add something like `.FindIndex(item => item.RoomId >= 1 && item.RoomId <= 25)` so it answers the question, or maybe it won't, we don't know if OP wants to get every indexes or only the first one

Comment: Doesn't this return just one index?

Comment: @Isma `IndexOf` also returns the index of the first occurence

Comment: But he wants to get several indexes at once, I think...